# Clang-Format: Open brace on newline after multiline statement

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

I'm looking for a way to conditionally set the opening brace on a newline only after the statement that preceded it spanned multiple lines.

For example

```
void foo() {  // single line
}

void bar(int aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
         int bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb)
{  // declaration of bar spanned multiple lines, brace on newline.
}

for (int i = 0;
     i < 10; ++i)
{  // for loop spanned multiple lines, so brace on newline.
}
```

Is there any rule that allows this in clang format? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: No. https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Comment: You cannot break for loop like that

Comment: Yes you can => https://reviews.llvm.org/D68296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.clang-format**

```
BraceWrapping:
  AfterControlStatement: MultiLine
```

[Feature proposal and merged](https://reviews.llvm.org/D68296)

Comment: This does not apply to function definitions, though, does it?